# Objective - C, fastest way to show sequence of images in UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, ios, performance, ios4, uiimageview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to efficiently show many Images? (iPhone programming)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507441/how-to-efficiently-show-many-images-iphone-programming)

I have hundreds of images, which are frame images of one animation **(24 images per second)**. Each image size is **1024x690**.
My problem is, I need to make **smooth animation iterating each image** frame in **UIImageView**.
I know I can use animationImages of **UIImageView**. But it crashes, because of memory problem.
Also, I can use `imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""]` that would cache each image, so that the next repeat animation will be **smooth**. But, caching a lot of images crashed app.
Now I use `imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@""]`, which does not crash app, but doesn't make animation so smooth. 
Maybe there is a better way to make good animation of frame images?
*Maybe I need to make some preparations, in order to somehow achieve better result. I need your advices. Thank you!*

Comment: UIImageView *animation.frame = [UIImageView new];
    animation.animationImages = animationFrames; // array of images
    animation.animationDuration = 1.25;
    animation.animationRepeatCount = 1;
 animation.hidden = YES;
try this

Answer (score 1):

You can find your answer here: [How to efficiently show many Images? (iPhone programming)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507441/how-to-efficiently-show-many-images-iphone-programming?rq=1)

To summarize what is said in that link, you get better performance when showing many images if you use low level API's like Core Animation and OpenGL, as oppose to UIKit.

Answer (score 1):

You could try caching say 10 images at a time in memory (you may have to play around with the correct limit -- i doubt it's 10). Everytime you change the image of the imageView you could do something like this:

```
// remove the image that is currently displayed from the cache
[images removeObjectAtIndex:0];
// set the image to the next image in the cache
imageView.image = [images objectAtIndex:0];
// add a new image to the end of the FIFO
[images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"10thImage.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a buffer of several images using an array.  This buffer array of images can be loaded/populated using imageWithContentsOfFile from a background thread (a concurrent GCD asynchronous, for example).