# Memory management of many UIImageViews

Tags: ios, memory, memory-management, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I'm making an iOS app in which, if memory were not an issue, there would be thousands of images loaded on the screen simultaneously. Obviously, this is not a good approach, so what I want to do is "unrender" some of these images so that only a few are on screen at any given point, and then "rerender" them when the user takes certain actions. So my question is, how could I do this?

Or, if it's any easier, all of the images are the same; I know this may sound kind of weird, but yes my app could require thousands of the same image to be loaded on screen. Since this is the case, is memory management not really an issue since they'll all be referencing the same file? (and by not an issue, I mean such that I can just use the `hidden` property to change what is and is not on screen). If I can do this, I was doing

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"image.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[scrollView addSubview:imageView];
```

(scrollView is a `UIScrollView` that I was using to give pinch to zoom functionality to the `UIImageView`). The issue, though, is that when I do this the `UIImageView` isn't rendered at all.

Any other ideas or suggestions are of course appreciated, and thanks in advance :D

Comment: duplicate of: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507441/how-to-efficiently-show-many-images-iphone-programming>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends upon your UI. When you say thousands of images, how many are visible at one time. Is it kind of like a huge photo gallery where only a few are actually visible at any given time? In that case, you'd probably just maintain views for just the images visible at the time, and the ones that are scrolled off the visible screen will not have any views associated with them until they scroll on (and those that are were visible but are now scrolled off will be released).

But if you're dealing with a different problem, tons of little images, many of which may be visible at the same time, that's a different problem (addressed with [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507441) like that provided by qegal).

I assume you're trying to do something more like the latter, but regardless, you have to give us a slightly better idea of the nature of the images and what sort of user experience we're dealing with here.

**Update:**

Sounds like you're doing something more like the former. In that case...

Check out [PhotoScroller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010080), Apple's example of navigation through a large collection of images (only three images are in the app, but you get the idea).

Personally, I have a low tech implementation, where I have a photo browser where I'm panning horizontally (UIPanGestureRecognizer) through a large collection of images (roughly 100, but could just as easily be many, many more). My view controller, though, only has three UIImageView controls, one for the main image being shown, one for the one to the previous image (and it's frame is set just off screen to the left), and one for the next image (and it's frame is set just off screen to the right). As I receive continuous feedback from the UIPanGestureRecognizer, I adjust all three frames by the horizontal portion of the translationInView of the gesture recognizer (I've seen other implementations that use a scrollview to coordinate the movements of the images, but the idea is still the same). When I let go, my gesture recognizer figures out whether I successfully swiped to the next or previous image, completes that animation, and when it's done, it relocates the three UIImageViews (previous offscreen to the left, current on screen, and next offscreen to the right) and reloads the three image views with the appropriate "current", "previous", and "next" images. At that point you're ready for another swipe with your gesture recognizer.

Comment: I looked at the link provided by qegal, but the issue is that the images I want are 640x960, much larger than the 17x1 as in that link, and at any given point hundreds may be visible, and more may exist but not be on screen. What I want to do is delete from memory the ones that aren't currently on screen so I don't use an obscene amount of memory in trying to render all of them at once. My situation is more like your first example, but I'm kinda stumped on how to implement that… any ideas? :)

Comment: @user1226490 Updated answer with two solutions, Apple's example, and my primitive solution (that I did before I realized that Apple had this sample project).

Comment: Although those are good ideas, I'm still not 100% if that's what I'm looking for. I have an idea, but tell me if this won't work:I have a custom class that represents each picture, and this class has an instance variable of type `UIImageView` that is the picture on screen. The `UIImage` for that is stored in a singleton object so I'm not always storing new pictures in memory each time I instantiate a new object (is this true? or will it store them anyway?). If I just set the `UIImage` in each `UIImageView` to `nil` whenever I don't want it on screen, will this work in reducing memory overhead?

Comment: @user1226490 While I'm not sure if I follow all of the particulars of your approach (I don't even know what your UI is; is it a photo gallery or something else?), it strikes me that the goal would be to _not_ have have hundreds/thousands of UIImage and/or UIImageView objects associated with the images, but just have the one (or three or whatever the smallest subset you need to support your UI and its animation), and then fill the UIImages and UIImageViews with the few images that you actually need at the given moment.

Comment: @user1226490 While I understand the conceptual attractiveness of the UIImage singleton, as you describe it, I'm not sure I'd want to have hundreds/thousands of UIImageView objects either. And I'm not sure I'd want a singleton for my image, because if and when you get into animation of images on and off of the screen, it's useful to have a couple of them around. I'd vote for the limited UIImageViews, each with it's own UIImage, and do your UI magic to give the user the appearance of navigating between the thousands of images, while putting negligible strain on the OS. My two cents.

Comment: Alright thanks, you've given me some good ideas and after thinking about them, I think I have come up with a solution that just might work. I'm sorry I was so vague with my UI, it's not a photo gallery but rather something very specific to my app, and not that I don't trust you, but since anyone can see this thread I'm not exactly comfortable posting my idea. So thanks for your help :)